# NHibernate Linq Query

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I have an nHibernate issue with the following Linq Query.  The session is not recognized.  I'm sure I'm just mising a using directive or something similar.  Any ideas?

```
var posts = (from post in session.Query<Post>().FetchMany(x => x.Comments) 
         select post).ToList();
```

Comment: You're going to need to provide a little more info or code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.FetchMany` requires `using NHibernate.Linq;`